# Pygments isn't loaded in trac

Tags: trac, pygments

I've installed Pygments on a TRAC server, but after restarting the TRAC service, Pygments isn't loaded.

After restarting the TRAC service, the log file looks like this:

```
2015-03-07 20:34:52,496 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading trac.mimeview.patch from c:\python27\lib\site-packages 
2015-03-07 20:34:52,496 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading trac.mimeview.pygments from c:\python27\lib\site-packages
2015-03-07 20:34:52,513 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Skipping "trac.mimeview.pygments = trac.mimeview.pygments [pygments]": ("DistributionNotFound: Pygments>=0.6" not found)
2015-03-07 20:34:52,513 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading trac.mimeview.rst from c:\python27\lib\site-packages
2015-03-07 20:34:52,513 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Skipping "trac.mimeview.rst = trac.mimeview.rst [rest]": ("DistributionNotFound: docutils>=0.3" not found)
2015-03-07 20:34:52,513 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading trac.mimeview.silvercity from c:\python27\lib\site-packages
2015-03-07 20:34:52,529 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Skipping "trac.mimeview.silvercity = trac.mimeview.silvercity [silvercity]": ("DistributionNotFound: SilverCity>=0.9.4" not found)
2015-03-07 20:34:52,529 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading trac.mimeview.txtl from c:\python27\lib\site-packages
2015-03-07 20:34:52,529 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Skipping "trac.mimeview.txtl = trac.mimeview.txtl [textile]": ("DistributionNotFound: textile>=2.0" not found)
```

With 'pip show pygments' I've verified the Pygments installation, version 2.0.2 is installed in the 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages' folder.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Trac 1.0.3 or later (preferably 1.0.4) with Pygments 2.x. See [#11796](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11796). You should install [Pygments 1.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments/1.6) if you are stuck with an earlier version of Trac.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I'm using TRAC 0.12. With Pygments 1.6 it's functional now.